# The action 'create' could not be found for PostsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am doing the tutorial for Rails, starting up the web server.

I am at the 5.8 listing and I get this error:

> Unknown action
>
> The action 'create' could not be found for PostsController

These are the files:

postcontroller.rb:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))

    @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end 

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
  end
end
```

What is causing the error?

Comment: Post your routes.rb code.

Comment: i'm not sure what is causing the error, sorry but i cant found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You list the filename as `postcontroller.rb` but Rails will expect it to be defined at:

`app/controllers/posts_controller.rb`

Comment: that was a mistake, the real filename in the filetree is like you called: posts_controller(i forgot '_')

Answer (score 1):

Check your `/config/routes.rb` make sure that you have resources :posts

Modify your new action

```
def new
 @post = Post.new
end
```

also for `index action` you will get an error when you call it
make it `@post` NOT `@posts`

Comment: that is the bloc:
  [link]  Blog::Application.routes.draw do
        resources :posts
        root to: "Welcome#index"
       end

Comment: i changed "s" in    def index(within posts_controller.rb). now i get another error. im following the whole "tuto" until the end. duno if that will solve the problem, just im keeping ahead, couse the first problem is not solved.

Comment: have you modified `new action` ? and what error you are getting ?

Comment: i had implemented the method, like you writed above.              "@post = Post.new", in posts_controller.rb. It was defined in first steps of that "tuto", but was empty.

Comment: i get this error now : undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass

Comment: post your view form which raises the error to see if i can help

Comment: <h1>New Post</h1>
<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
 <% if @post.errors.any? %>
 <div id="errorExplanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %>
prohibited
   this post from being saved:</h2>
  <ul> 
  <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %> 
  </ul>
 </div>
 <% end %>

 <p>
 <%= f.label :title %><br>
 <%= f.text_field :title %>
 </p>
 
 <p>
  <%= f.label :text %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :text %>
 </p>

 <p> 
  <%= f.submit %>
 </p> 
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>

Comment: 1:  <h1>New Post</h1>
2: <%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
3:  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
4:  <div id="errorExplanation">
5:   <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %>    NoMethodError in Posts#new undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass

Comment: from the tutorial you follow , it said that >> The reason why we added `@post = Post.new` in `posts_controller` is that otherwise `@post` would be `nil` in our view, and calling `@post.errors.any?` would throw an error. -- so do you have `@post = Post.new` in your new action or you have removed it ?

Comment: i have it. in posts_controller.rb (the first method, after the class declaration)